# Implementing Business Logic in Architecture

Tags: architecture, enterprise-architecture, architectural-patterns, angularjs

I am currently making architecture for one application in which we have different types of user and every user has different types of functionalities to perform.

I am confuse in one point if i try to implement the business logic according to user types the architecture becomes tightly couple where as the code is more organize. Like I want to create every user type as a module and inside of that module I want to have every page is a module and inside the page I have components.
Further I also have shared module which is components which can be shared in every module of the user. I am confuse if its the right approach or by doing this I am making the architecture tightly coupled with business logic which can effect changes later.

Comment: you can assign role for that, and show things according to that role.

Comment: You seem to be conflating what architecture to use with how you want to structure your view files in your solution. These are two separate concerns.

Answer (score 2):

So it sounds like you want to implement some sort of access control.

You suggest to give each user one specific type and then creating a module per type that has the features that type needs.

While this can work, it will most likely lead to a lot of duplication. For example, in a webshop, "guest", "registered user" and "admin" can all "view index", "view category", "view product" and much more. In addition, both "registered user" and "admin" may be able to "add review", "place order" and "view order". You can sort of solve this with inheritance, but only if there is nothing that "guest" can do that "registered user" or "admin" cannot - which isn't the case in this example, because a "guest" can "create account" while a "registered user" cannot and then "admin" once again can.

As you can see, this will become rather messy rather quick.

What you could do instead is create an access control list (ACL). This is basically a list of "user type A can do action 1" entries. The code of action 1 then starts with something like this:

```
if (!this.acl.can(user, "action1")) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException()
}
```

Depending on the situation, it could be better to have this in one central location in the dispatch process. If you do that, you need some code that checks the ACL before calling the function that contains the business logic. It has the benefits that you cannot forget the check and that the business logic is unaware of the checks. A drawback is that you lose a little bit of flexibility (for instance, to have such a check halfway trough a routine to provide extra functionality).

An AngularJS example of how that could work can be found at https://coderwall.com/p/f6brkg/angularjs-access-control-and-authentication

In addition to this move away from "a module per user type", you could move from "a user has one type" to "a user has multiple roles". That makes the administration of permissions easier (don't have to give that new permission to all 8 user types) at the cost of making individual user administration a bit harder (might have to give that new role to all 4352 users - though that is probably a rarer case).

Comment: I got your point. The thing is that every user has different types of pages. Yes it is possible that every page has same functionality or maybe some pages can have access to all the user. This is why i am making a shared component in the core. Where the shared components like category, products are created and i am thinking to use them inside the page module. so there would be no or less duplication of code. Where as on the other hand if we want to add or delete any component or change the layout of the page. We can easily do it in the page level.

Comment: Well, what I described would also work in the situation that there is absolutely 0 overlap, without much (if any) downsides. Having a module per user type can limit you in the future if it turns out you need more flexibility.

Comment: Totally anecdotal: I worked on an application with a module per user type. In the beginning, there was a "base" type that all other types inherited from and then 4 concrete types that could add or overwrite things. We ended up with code that was 90% the same in multiple of the concrete types - that wasn't the plan initially, but it happened over time (a few years) as requirements changed.

Comment: Can't stress enough that `a user has multiple roles` is **_the_** key piece you need to take away from this answer. The question of who can do what is important to "the business" but in an application, it is not business logic --- it is **authorization**.